# Send message to C# with JSocket (SWF)

Tags: c#, javascript, jsocket

So I have just started using JS and wanted to do something simple (at least it seemed simple a few hours ago), I wanted to send a msg ("Hello World") via JS (using Xampp) to my (local) server in VC#. It failed in every attempt. Can anyone help? or link me to any good tutorial?
So my last code was:
JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsocket.js"></script>

    <title> Basic Java Code </title>
</head>
<body>      
     <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.write('Starting script');
        var host = '127.0.0.1'; 
        var port = 3000;

        var socket = new jSocket();



        //socket.onReady = function(){
            socket.connect(host, port);             
        //}socket.emit('Hello world');   

        socket.onConnect = function(success, msg){
            if(success){
                    socket.write('Hello world');            
            }else{
                    alert('Connection to the server could not be estabilished: ' + msg);            
            }       
        }
        socket.onData = function(data){
            alert('Received from socket: '+data);   
        }

        socket.setup('mySocket');       

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: signalR would probably make this a lot easier

Comment: K. thx will look into it.